# How convert jQuery addClass code to Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have the following jQuery code that is used for adding some animations to a Signup form when clicking on the submit button.

```
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#new-user-layout').addClass('animate__fadeOut')
        }, 1000)
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#new-user-layout').addClass('hidden')
        }, 1300)
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#new-user-layout').removeClass('animate__fadeOut')
            $('.app-login_form-layout').css({ 'height': '28rem', 'width': '25rem' })
        }, 1600)
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#user_credentials').removeClass('hidden')
            $('#user_credentials').addClass('animate__fadeIn')
        }, 2000)
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#user_credentials').removeClass('animate__fadeIn')
        }, 2300)
```

Now this is with the HTML template that I need to convert to Angular code. How can I add these animation classes in Angular way ?

I tried using `[ngClass]`, but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewChild`, `ElementRef` and `Renderer2` as below

```
@ViewChild("newuserlayout") newuserlayout: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      debugger;
      this.renderer.addClass(
        this.newuserlayout.nativeElement,
        "animate__fadeOut"
      );
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-elementref-render2

Comment: Elegant. You are awesome !!! Thanks a lot. This is the perfect solution.

Comment: Meh.. why not use Angular animations for this?

Comment: @MikeOne how that can be used ?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://angular.io/guide/animations